# Does quotaUser even work for calendar api

Tags: google-calendar-api

- We use service account impersonation to fetch events of users in an organization.
- When we dont use the quotaUser , we get rate limited due to the Queries per minute per user . This is expected
- However when we set the quota to a Really low value ie 1 and ensure that we invoke fetch events for unique users only lets say 25, and additionally use quotaUser , we dont expect to see rate limiting.
- However we are experiencing rate limiting.

Below is what we tried

1. We have setup a test organization with 25 users
2. We set up the Queries per minute per user to a really low value i.e 1
3. We ensured to pass in quotaUser while we invoked calendar.events.list
4. We expected that we see no rate limiting of whatsoever coz those users are unique and we have not hit the threshold of 1 at all